# Google Sheets API nodejs - get index of the cell that contains a string

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

First of all, how exactly do I access the contents of a cell? I'm creating a discord bot that displays the stats of different units in a game using the game's public spreadsheet values: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WqogbXoOThLkt2kL3QJbFGT3Kc_x_XwwmK2FCJdrnvQ/edit#gid=1714057504

So the user would type in the mini's (unit's) name, and I need to find the cell that contains the unit's name and then get the values of its stats, which would be on the same row.

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, there are a lot of sheets in the Spreadsheet. So I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect from your sample Spreadsheet? By the way, in your goal, is it required to use only Node.js?

Comment: @Tanaike the user would input the name of a unit, for example "Turret Truck", and the code needs to find that "Turret Truck" is in the sheet "Republic Minis" and then output the values of pretty much everything on the row of "Turret Truck", but it needs to know what each value corresponds to (i.e. that 40 is the "max level")

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about the sample input and output you expect from your sample Spreadsheet. And also, I couldn't understand whether you are required to use only Node.js.

Comment: It's ok I managed to figure out how to do it, thanks for the response though

Comment: If you came up with a solution please post it as an answer so other people may benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

@Raserhin suggested I post how I solved my problem so here it is.

I used `spreadsheets.values.get()` to get the data for the sheets. `data.values` is apparently a 2D array, so that makes everything easy now, so I can follow @Query's suggestion. I repeated for each of the 3 sheets (since there are 3 factions of units in the game). I put all 2D arrays in a 3D array. Then when a user inputs the name of a unit, there is an outer for loop that iterates 3 times for each faction, then nested within it is another for loop to iterate for each unit name, each time checking if the name matches the user input.

```
const {google} = require("googleapis");
const sheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: APIKey});

async function gsrun(cl){
    const opt = {
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: 'Republic Minis'
    };
          
    let repData = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    let repDataArray = repData.data.values;
    
    opt.range = 'Dominion Minis';
    let domData = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    let domDataArray = domData.data.values;

    opt.range = 'Empire Minis';
    let empData = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    let empDataArray = empData.data.values;

    var miniArray = [repDataArray, domDataArray, empDataArray];

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The google sheets API does not support lookup by value.

Seeings as you only have viewing permissions to the sheet the only feasible solution would be to iterate through the rows of the sheet in the for loop and break out when a match is found.

There are other solutions such as using a formula with the LOOKUP function but that would require write permissions to the document.

Comment: I'm quite new to Google Sheets api and I don't even know the syntax for that, how do I actually access the values in the cells?